# Problems with document structure and bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have to finish my thesis. The structure is something like this:

- Title
- Preface
- Abstract
- TOC etc...
- Part 1: part title
- ----- Chapter 1
- ----- Chapter 2
- Part 2: part title
- ----- Chapter 1
- ----- Chapter 2
- Bibliography

I use this code to generate the bibliography

```
\newpage{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Literaturverzeichnis}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\bibliographystyle{myamsalpha}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bibname}\nocite{*}
\bibliography{Zitate}
```

Unfortunately, the bibliography is not sorted into the correct level, meaning I would like to have the bibliography on the same level as the TOC for example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}` should automatically provide the correct ToC entry, no need to manipulate directly with `\addcontentsline`. However, I don't think, that a bibliography should be organized on the part level

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: so you would suggest adding a bibliography for each part seperately?

Comment: No, I didn't imply that. A `bibliography` has a chapter title heading normally, but's not a `\part` or `\chapter` of its own.

Comment: Not related to the problem: But why is there an empty group after `\newpage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 'minimal' structure, with the `bibliography` entry in the ToC on the some level as chapters. Usually, it's sufficient to use `\usepackage{tocbibind}` to get several list of contents etc. into the ToC itself.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

% Vorwort hier

% Abstract hier

\tableofcontents
\part{Faust -- der Trag\"odie Erster Teil}
\chapter{Kapitel 1}
\chapter{Kapitel 2}
\blindtext


\part{Faust -- der Trag\"odie Zweiter Teil}
\chapter{Kapitel 3}
\chapter{Kapitel 4}

%%%%%


\pagestyle{fancy}
\cleardoublepage
\lhead{\bibname}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}\nocite{*}
\bibliography{zitate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it might be desired to have a vertical space between the last chapter of part 2 and the bibliography entry.  inserting `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{<some dimension>}}` after the `\cleardoublepage` would do the job.  (do check the spelling of the command before using; i always get it wrong first time, and am not in a position to check it right now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Basically the same what `\chapter` etc. is adding to the `LoF` etc. I could do that, but its rather unusual in German style

Comment: good point about the difference in "regional" style.  the extra space *would* be added for a book published by the ams.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I think it's `amsbook` or where is `myamsalpha` coming from?

Comment: `myamsalpha` is most likely a local modification of `amsalpha.bst`.  it has nothing to do with whether there is an entry in the toc; that's up to the document class.  (`amsbook` automatically puts an entry for the biblio in the toc, but it doesn't add extra space above the entry in a case like this.  that's always an editorial addition if the author hasn't done it.  could be made automatic by checking whether `\part` has been used, but isn't there now.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I know, it must be a `.bst` file.